# iOS - Detect when an alertview appears on screen

Tags: ios, ios7, uialertview, detect

Is there any way to figure-out in presented view controller when some alertview appears on screen from some other controller. I do not want to pass any block, delegate or fire any notification.

Comment: But I have mention that I would not want to use any notification listener.

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand, aren't you supposed to have to call [alertView show] in order for the alertView to show? so why would you need some extra mechanism to detect this event?

Comment: No I don't, lets say I am using a library which show popup on some event but never fire any event which indicate that some alertview is being shown.

Comment: OKay, now I understand your needs, but unfortunately have no answer for it. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have mac now. I'm posting it from windows machine. So i could not able to check whether its perfect code or not.
When `UIAlertView` is presented, it'll be presented as another `UIWindow`. So you can check it with `UIApplication` singleton methods. Like

```
UIAlertview *secondWindowisThere  = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] objectAtIndex:1]
```

If you sure that you're having **two windows**, then you can check that with using method `isKindofClass`, Like,

```
if([secondWindowisThere isKindofClass:[UIAlertview Class]]) {
// your code here
}
```